# what does # mean in javascript

Tags: javascript, web-component

Came across something I cant find in docs.  This `#selectedIndex = 0;` what does `#` do?

```
class WcTabPanel extends HTMLElement {
    static observedAttributes = ["selected-index", "direction"];
    #selectedIndex = 0;
```

appears in this example https://codepen.io/ndesmic/pen/mdELqbM

Comment: [Private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)

Comment: You might want to refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64968964/what-does-the-symbol-do-in-javascript

Comment: See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means `private field`.

Class fields are public by default, but private class members can be created by using a hash # prefix. The privacy encapsulation of these class features is enforced by JavaScript itself.

You can find documentation here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields).